# Как перезапустить второй поток в QThread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, pyqt5, qthread

Я делаю программу "напоминание" с помощью PyQt5.

В ней идёт 2 потока, первый основной (pyqt5) и второй отвечает за оповещение напоминаний.

Проблема в том, что для второго потока мне нужно знать ближайшее напоминание. Сначала я передавал его в качестве аргумента при создании потока, но если я в первом потоке добавлю более новое напоминание, то во втором потоке данные устареют. Как мне обновлять данные во втором потоке (передавать из первого потока во второй)? Я гуглил как перезапустить поток(с новыми данными), но что-то толком ничего не нашёл.

Основной поток:

```
class Logic(QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi() # запускаем окно
        self.min_date = self.upcomingEvent()[0] # ищем ближайшее напоминание
        self.content = self.upcomingEvent()[1] # ищем ближайшее напоминание

        self.addBtn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.addRemider()) # добавляем напоминание

        self.thread = SecondStream(self.min_date) # создаём поток
        self.thread.start() # запускаем поток
```

Второй поток:

```
class SecondStream(QThread):
    def __init__(self, min_date):
        super().__init__()
        self.min_date = min_date

    def run(self):
        while True:
            date_now = date(datetime.now().year, datetime.now().month, datetime.now().day)
            if self.min_date == date_now:
                print("Напоминание")
            sleep(60)
```

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста [mcve]

Comment: Я внёс правки в код.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764821/qt-restarting-thread

Comment: вы почему-то не предоставляете минимально-воспроизводимый пример?
Мои высказывания субъективные и вы можете к ним относиться философски.
Судя по наличию метода `self.addRemider`` данные о напоминаниях у вас где-то хранятся.
Вот и проверяйте необходимость отправки напоминания в основном потоке (QTimer).
Дополнительный поток вам нужен для того, чтобы послать сообщение 
и это может быть трудоемкой задачей.

Comment: Т.е. в основном потоке поймали, что надо что-то отправлять, 
это что-то передаете в дополнительный поток и пытаетесь отправить.
О результатах работы функции `send_email` вы должны оповестить 
основной поток для принятия решения отметить ли данное сообщение 
как отправленное или что с ним делать дальше (например, попытаться отправить еще раз).